# Conexion base de datos en JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Estoy intentando conectarme con la base de datos mediante JSP y en eclipse, pero me da error.

He importado las librerias de MySQL, he  puesto conectores.. y sigue sin funcionarme, este es el código:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%> 
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>  
<%
    //Parámetro
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre-form");
    String apellidos = request.getParameter("apellidos-form");
    String edad = request.getParameter("edad-form");    

    String mensaje = nombre + " " + apellidos + " " + edad;


    Connection con = null;
    Statement set = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/personas","root", "root");
        set = con.createStatement();
        System.out.print("La conexion se ha aprobado");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error en acceso a base de datos" + e);
    }
```

Cuando intento conectarme no me entra por el `try`, me hace el `catch`, 
el error que me sale es el siguiente:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Falta disponer la librería JDBC de MySql en el directorio correspondiente

Comment: @Alfabravo Como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 1):

El error es muy claro. Estás intentando usar la clase `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` y en ninguno de tus import se está incluyendo. Seguramente, además, tampoco la tengas en las librerías de tu proyecto.

Como con cualquier librería "3rd-party" que se use como un archivo JAR en una webapp, sólo se necesita copiar/pegar el archivo JAR en la carpeta /WEB-INF/lib de tu aplicación. Así estará disponible en el classpath por defecto de la aplicación. Además, Eclipse es capaz de detectar la nueva librería y usarla en el proyecto sin mayor lío.

La descarga del JAR (a mayo 22 de 2018) está [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Te recomiendo además, leer cómo funcionan las conexiones JDBC ya que estabas usando código sin entenderlo.

**Edito:** Todo indica que no está en el classpath. Para añadir la librería a tu classpath, es necesario:

Clic derecho en el proyecto -- > Opción `build path` -- > Opción `configure build path`

En la pestaña `Libraries` haz clic en `Add External Jar` y selecciona el JAR del driver. Debería usarlo ahora sí.

Comment: Sí, lo se @Alfabravo, tenía puesto en el 'lib' de mi proyecto el archivo JAR que me está diciendo pero aun así sigue sin funcionar, respecto al import que me está diciendo, ¿cuál debería poner?

Comment: Directorio `/WEB-INF/lib`, confirma que es ese, por favor

Comment: Confirmado, sigue igual. @Alfabravo